# Laravel 4 - Convert arrays of objects into individual objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel, laravel-4

I hope you can help me with this simple problem in converting arrays of objects to individual objects. So I can directly call their attributes.

What I mean is, I have this data listed below:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#259 (8) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["author_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["title"]=>
    string(17) "The Emperorasdasd"
    ["publisher"]=>
    string(15) "De publishing"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2013-10-11 12:49:00"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2013-10-12 09:44:58"
    ["date_published"]=>
    string(10) "02-12-2013"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#260 (8) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["author_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Demo"
    ["publisher"]=>
    string(10) "ooqwwoeqoe"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2013-10-12 09:45:31"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2013-10-12 09:45:36"
    ["date_published"]=>
    string(10) "26-12-1993"
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Demo"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#261 (8) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["author_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["title"]=>
    string(12) "Read My Mind"
    ["publisher"]=>
    string(13) "TF Publishing"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2013-10-12 09:46:53"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2013-10-12 09:46:53"
    ["date_published"]=>
    string(10) "30-11-2009"
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "James Mones"
  }
}
```

How will I convert the 3 item array into 3 individual objects? So I can call them directly like: `$books->id`, not `$books[0]->id` ?

Answer (score 2):

Its not 100% clear what you mean, whether you want the three objects as seperate variables or you just need a way of accessing them.

A simple foreach should suffice.

```
foreach ( $collection as $model ) 
{
    $id = $model->id;
}
```

alternatively the answer supplied by Eugen would grab specific indexes to variables for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

Is this, what you mean?

```
$book0 =& $books[0];
$book1 =& $books[1];
$book2 =& $books[2];

echo $book0->id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
list($books1, $books2, $books3) = $arrayOfObjects;
```

[**DEMO.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CShp01)

So, if your `$arrayOfObjects` has three objects inside it then every objects will be extracted from the array and will be stored in variables supplied in the `list` and you can use the first object like

```
echo $books1->id;
echo $books2->id;
echo $books3->id;
```

Also, using a loop you can do it like

```
foreach($arrayOfObjects as $books) {
    echo $books->id;
}
```