# Array to int conversion in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

How to convert array members to int. 
My controller code

```
    public function show()
{
    $i = DB::table('users')->lists('id');
     // var_dump($i);
    return View::make('seat.seatselect')->with('i', $i);
}
```

When I var_dump($i) it result is as following

```
array(12) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(14) [2]=> int(16) [3]=> int(17) [4]=> int(18) [5]=> int(19) [6]=> int(20) [7]=> int(21) [8]=> int(22) [9]=> int(23) [10]=> int(24) [11]=> int(26) }
```

So in my view I call $i. Resu is coming only last value of $i

```
@foreach($i as $i)
    var bookedSeats = [{{$i}}];
@endforeach
```

But I want to retrieve the result as followed
Example:

```
var bookedSeats = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 13, 56];
```

How to solve it. Help me please.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333160/laravel-4-convert-arrays-of-objects-into-individual-objects

Comment: I know how to  call individual objects. But I want put to inside bookedSeats var seperate by comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you don't want a PHP variable named $bookedSeats that is set to an array, but a JavaScript array generated from those PHP values. In that case, you could simply do this:

```
var bookedSeats = [{{ implode(', ', $i) }}];
```

No need for a foreach. :)

Comment: Thanks bro. This is working. var bookedSeats = [{{ implode(', ', $i) }}];

Answer (score 0):

If this is a js code:

```
@foreach($i ass $i)
    var bookedSeats = [{{$i}}];
@endforeach
```

try changing it to:

```
var bookedSeats = [];
@foreach($i ass $i)
    bookedSeats.push({{ $i }});
@endforeach
```